# Pandas add column with value by matching similar names from 2 different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a Champions League Fantasy statistic table, and I'm getting data from 2 different sites that name the player slightly different between each other.

I have df1 from site 1:

```
             Name  Pos
0    Lionel Messi  DEL
1  Junior Messias  DEL
2            Kepa  POR
3         Alisson  POR
```

and df2 from site 2:

```
                Name  Cost
0              Messi    40
1            Messias    20
2  Kepa Arrizabalaga    10
3             Neymar    40
```

Note that Messi is still Messi but in one site they call him by his full name and in the other they call him by his last name.
The same for the last one Kepa Arrizabalaga.

What I want to do is add a column `'Cost'` in `df1` with the corresponding cost of the player. The challenge here is that if I try to look for the word 'Messi' in `df2` to look for his cost, I will potentially get the Junior Messias cost because 'Messi' is in his last name, so I was thinking in the `SequenceMatcher.ratio()` type of solution, but I tried that for the player Kepa and of course 'Kepa' is very different from 'Kepa Arrizabalaga' so I won't get a close match on that one.
I don't know how to parse `df1` and find a close-enough match of the `'Name'` column on the `df2` to look for its cost and add it to `df1`.

The desire output for `df3` would be as follows:

```
             Name  Pos Cost
0    Lionel Messi  DEL   40
1  Junior Messias  DEL   20
2            Kepa  POR   10
3         Alisson  POR  NaN
```

Comment: How many rows does your df have?

Comment: Will there be any duplicates? e.g., can there be the same first/last name in multiple rows of either df?

Comment: It could have over 2000 rows, they are a lot of players

Comment: No, there are not gong to be any duplicates in a single df

Comment: So ALL first names AND last names are going to be unique? There aren't going to be two people where, say, the have different first names but the same last name?

Comment: Oh right right, no, there might be duplicates like that, for example Roberto Gagliardini and Roberto Firmino, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240155/discussion-between-ivan-diaz-de-leon-and-user17242583).